# jQuery Mobile 1.9.1 popup menu load

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Here is my html code:

```
<a href="#adresbulalim" data-rel="popup" data-icon="search" class="headerButton" data-role="button">Adres Ara</a>


<div data-role="popup" id="adresbulalim" data-theme="d">

        <div id="wrapperilceler">

    <div id="scrollerilceler">
      <li id="baslikadres"  data-role="divider" data-theme="e">İlçe Seçiniz</li>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"  data-theme="d" id="doldur" style="min-width:210px;">



        </ul>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).delegate("#adresbulalim", "click", function() { 



        });
```

I want to do that when I click on Adres Ara button, open popup menu and and work function. Every opening popup menu, must run function.

Simply I explain like that, I have popup menu and for example when I click ok button, it will open and on the background function run. When I close popup menu and after again click ok button, it will again open and function run again.

Thanks.

Comment: The popup widget has callbacks, you can use the afteropen: $("#adresbulalim").on("popupafteropen", function(event, ui) {} );

Comment: If you want to use the click event, then assign an ID to the A tag and then use it $(document).on("click", "#aid", function(){ //code here});